# how to only allow 3 values in a "if" and "while" statement to allow the loop to exit

Tags: c++

I'm just stuck on some logic statements.

specifically the ones that are in the function `char GetInteger()` so how would I only allow 3 values to cause the loop to exit.

```
char GetInteger( /* out */ char& usrinput)
{
    do
    {
        cin >> usrinput;
        cin.ignore(200,'\n');
        if (usrinput != 0 || usrinput != 1 || usrinput != 2)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << userinput << " Try Again\n";
        }

    } while(usrinput != 0 || usrinput != 1 || usrinput != 2);

    return userInput;
}
```

Comment: `usrinput` is a `std::string`, comparing it to `2` makes no sense. `while(usrinput !<= 2)` is invalid syntax even if it was a number. You can't assign the value of a function you've declared as returning `void`, because it doesn't have one.

Comment: so should I change the data type of `usrinput`? and how would i get it to check for it only being a value of 0-2 and nothing more and no characters?

Comment: There is no actual question here. When you push the `Ask Question` button, you have to ask a specific question.

Comment: Also, your while loop will never terminate. Every possible input is  not zero, except zero. But zero is not one. So every number is not zero or not one.

Comment: Fixed code based on original question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/68472/507

Comment: @kuthedk: Now that the  code is working you should post on code review site (or redo the question you have asked).  There are some things we can do to improve your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues with this code:

First `userinput` has a type of char. So when you read from a stream you read a single character (after dropping white space). So when a user types `1<enter>` you get the character '1' in the variable `userinput`. Note the character `'1'` is not the same as the number `1`.

Thus your test should be:

```
userinput != '1';
```

Secondly your boolean logic is wrong. When first learning it is sometimes easier to state the problem as a list of values that you would like to be acceptable (not the unacceptable ones).

You want the conditions to be false if the userInput has one of your accepted values (any good value will fail the test and thus not invoke the bad code). The first step to this is to get a true if any of your values are valid.

```
// If any value is good then true.
userinput == '1' || userinput == '2' || userinput == '3'
```

To invert this just add a `not` to the expression.

```
if (! (userinput == '1' || userinput == '2' || userinput == '3') )
```

Note: in boolean logic

```
!(A || B)   =>  (!A && !B)
```

So you could re-write the above as:

```
if (userinput != '1' && userinput != '2' && userinput != '3')
```

I think this was your main mistake you converted the `==` into `!=` but did not convert the `||` into `&&`.

I would also suggest that you could simplify this (as you may get more valid result) byconverting this into a range based test.

```
 if (userinput < '1' || userinput > '3')
 {
      // Test Failed.
 }
```

Additionally. Since you have the test in two places. You should yank it outinto its own function. Then you can call the function to do the test.

```
 bool isUserInputValid(char userInput)
 {
     return userInput >= '1' && userInput <= '3';
 }
```

Now we can re-write your original function as:

```
char GetInteger( /* out */ char& usrinput)
{
    do
    {
        cin >> usrinput;
        cin.ignore(200,'\n');
        if (!isUserInputValid(userinput))
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input." << userinput << " Try Again\n";
        }

    } while(!isUserInputValid(userinput));

    return userInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use int instead of string as you are reading integer. 
You can use while(1) instead of putting condition in while. Inside while loop, if your selection is 0 or 1 or 2, you can simply break the loop.

Comment: I don't quite follow the last part, I'm trying to have it where it will continue a loop where if a user inputs 0-2 the functions defined in `int main()` will be able to either exit out of the program or count the vowels/constants from a user defined input file.